# Performing ellipsoid to spheroid conversion using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, ellipsoid, spheroid

I have a DTM that is referenced to an ellipsoid (equatorial radius is not equal to the polar radius) and I want to convert the elevation values to the spheroid (equatorial radius = polar radius).

How can this be done using ArcMap?

Additional info: The DTM is of a different planetary body.

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about ArcGIS Desktop or GDAL in this particular question. If it’s the former are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: @PolyGeo. I use ArcMap...

Comment: If you wish to also ask how to do this using GDAL then please do so in a separate question.

Comment: @PolyGeo Is it possible to do with ArcMap?

Comment: I suspect so but I’ll leave it for a geodesist to try and answer.

Comment: I would first make sure that your elevations are indeed referenced to an ellipsoid. Sometimes the horizontal datum is an ellipsoid, but the vertical datum can be something else. Check the metadata to see how the elevations were derived, and which elevation datum is used. For instance, with Mars, the elevations are referenced to the areoid (martian geoid), not an ellipsoid nor a sphere. So converting can require additional information in such cases.

Comment: @FSimardGIS I have the values of the polar and equatorial radii and I am certain that it is referenced to ask ellipsoid. How should I proceed from there?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a tool in ArcMap to do this. But it might be doable with python and a bit of math...